# Is it bad practice for get accessor to return a new instance?

Tags: c#

Are there issues with returning a new instance from an accessor? If so, is there a better approach?

```
public class Person
{
    private RecIpDet _ipDet;
    public RecIpDet IpDet
    {
        get 
        {                 
            if(_ipDet == null)
                _ipDet = new RecIpDet();
            return _ipDet; 
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Curious, why aren't you setting _ipDet to the new instance?

Comment: My fault that should be changed.

Comment: So what is the question then? Now, the get accessor isn't returning a new instance. The question doesn't match the title.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are issues, because you never set your field, so you'll return a new object everytime the property is called.

You should set `_ipDet` if it's null, and then return it. This is called [lazy instantiation or lazy initialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_initialization).

```
public class Person
{
    private RecIpDet _ipDet;

    public RecIpDet IpDet
    {
        get 
        {                 
            if (_ipDet == null)
            {
                _ipDet = new RecIpDet();
            }

            return _ipDet; 
        }
    } 
}
```

Keep in mind, this is not thread-safe, so if that's a factor for you, you'll need a more robust mechanism. For single threaded applications, this method of lazy instantiation is fine.

If you're using .NET 4.0 or higher, you can use the [`Lazy<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331.aspx) class, which I believe is thread-safe:

```
public class Person
{
    private Lazy<RecIpDet> _ipDet = new Lazy<RecIpDet>(() => new RecIpDet());

    public RecIpDet IpDet
    {
        get 
        {                 
            return _ipDet.Value; 
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 5):

For us it is common practice to use:

```
get
{
    return _ipDet ?? (_ipDet = new RecIpDet());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comment, it does appear you meant to set the instance, so this is a classic example of lazy instantiation which is fine (though not thread-safe).  If you do not need to worry about thread safety, then by all means this will work:

```
get
{
    if (_ipDet == null)
        _ipDet = new RecIpDet();

    return _ipDet
}
```

But if you're in .NET 4.0 I'd recommend `Lazy<T>` instead of building your own lazy construction:

```
public class Person
{
    private Lazy<RecIpDet> _ipDet = new Lazy<RecIpDet>();

    public RecIpDet IpDet
    {
        get { return _ipDet.Value; }
    } 
}
```

Lazy's Value calls the constructor for the type on first call and is thread-safe (you can choose different) levels of thread-safety as well..

Answer (score 1):

As of now you will always return a new object. Unless somehow _ipDet got set to a value. This makes your code behave very unpredictable.
Either implement the singleton pattern and replace  return new RecIpDet(); with _ipDet = new RecIpDet(); or make it always return a new object, which is fine.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite unusual to use **Lazy Instantiation**, most of the time it's for the **Singleton** pattern, here you'll find more info on that :

[Implementing Singleton pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx)

In this page you'll even find a way to make it thread-safe.

It can be very useful for global objects that can be accessed from anywhere in your application.